# Python indentation in Spacemacs with hard tabs is off

Tags: python, emacs, spacemacs

Let me preface by saying that I am a relatively new emacs/spacemacs convert from vim, so my my knowledge is still pretty basic.

I have spacemacs set up with the python layer, with the additional package of dtrt-indent listed in dotspacemacs-additional-packages. And setting

```
(dtrt-indent-mode t)
```

in the dotspacemacs/user-config. I need the dtrt-indent as I am working on a few projects (in python and lua) where I am not the one who sets the indentation rules.

This configuration works fine for python files with soft-tabs of varying length. This configuration also works for lua files that have hard tabs.

When I open a python file indented with hard tabs something seems to get messed up, it appears to think that the indentation is two hard tabs. Meaning, if I have code like this (pretend that the 4 spaces are tabs):

```
def func():|  <--- Cursor
    print 'line'
```

and press enter, I get:

```
def func():
        |  <--- Cursor
    print 'line'
```

The status line prints dtrt-indent's message saying:

```
Note: indent-tabs-mode adjusted to t
```

Note: As stated I'm pretty new at this, and my spacemacs configuration is pretty sparse. There is nothing else in my user-config, I have not custom layers, I don't even have any additional packages other than dtrt-indent.

EDIT:

python-indent-offset is set to 8

indent-tabs-mode is set to t

tab-width is set to 4

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try `M-x whitespace-mode` and repeat this experiment. What do you see? Did you indent with spaces or with tabs?

I'm guessing you'll see something like this:

```
def·func():
········
»   print·'line'
```

This would mean you have `python-indent-offset` set to 8, `indent-tabs-mode` set to nil (aka indent with spaces), and `tab-width` set to 4.

If that's not the case, what are the values of those variables (`C-h v python-indent-offset`, etc.)?

If that *is* the case, you can fix the problem by running

```
(setq-default python-indent-offset 4)
```

Comment: As mentioned in the edit, your guess was close but still correct. The indentation was actually two hard tabs and not 8 spaces, but setting the python-indent-offset to 4 did fix it. now I just need to figure out why dtrt-indent is setting the values improperly. If you have any suggestions I would appreciate it.

Comment: I took a look at the source code for `dtrt-mode` (`C-h f dtrt-mode`, click on `dtrt-indent.el`). It looks like it inherits from `standard-indent` so try putting `(setq standard-indent 4)` in your `.emacs`.