# How do I apply the spacemacs command (setq-default...)

Tags: spacemacs

So I'm new to spacemacs, and am having a problem with my python tabs. I found this [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37845243/python-indentation-in-spacemacs-with-hard-tabs-is-off/37870728) solution to the issue. The scenario he explained is exactly the problem Im having with my python layer, but I don't know how to apply the solution he gave, namely:

> If that is the case, you can fix the problem by running
>
> (setq-default python-indent-offset 4)

Where/how exactly do I run the command "(setq-default python-indent-offset 4)"? Do I put it in my spacemacs config? Or some where else?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer to this question as I was typing it up by way of the related questions ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172728/the-difference-between-setq-and-setq-default-in-emacs-lisp)).

Commands such as these go inside of your init.el config, which is accessed by typing SPC-f e i

Hope this helps all the spacemacs newbies out there. (Feel free anyone to correct me if i'm wrong or don't fully understand)

**Edit 1**

Just some background info for my answer for those who are curious. The command

`(setq-default python-indent-offset 4)`

is actually from the lisp family of programming languages. So spacemacs basically uses source code controlled configuration. It could probably have similarly went inside your spacemacs config as well (SPC f e d), although I believe init.el is the proper place for this type of setting

Comment: Is there any way to run it without adding to configuration?